# Failed to generate orderer genesis block - Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to run the startFabric.sh script but it fails with the following error.
[image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)[![enter image description here]

There are already several solutions posted for this problem. I went through almost all of them changing the FABRIC_CFG_PATH variable, running byfn.sh before this etc. etc. 
Still can not resolve!!

Comment: was the problem solved mate

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that you can run

```
./network.sh up
```

inside

```
fabric-samples/test-network/
```

?
The error you are getting maybe result of one of the followings:

1. You have an incomplete fabric-samples folder, OR
2. You do not have appropriate permission to access the folder which has config.yaml file. In this case, it's

   *fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp*
3. You do not have certificates generated for the orgs.

Please share more info, so it's easier to navigate through the problem

**P.S. The fabcar example in Fabric 2.1 uses test-network instead of first-network used in previous versions. So, running byfn.sh would not be of much help.**

Comment: yeah.. I am running the network.sh before running the startFabric.sh. I think the folder is complete also the certificates because its working fine when I run the network script. I also have confusion about the second point about permission. How do I check that?

Comment: If you are using windows, just Right-click on the folder and go to Properties> Security. Make sure that the user has the appropriate permission to access the folder. 

Have you tried running the CMD as an administrator? Try executing startFabric.sh after you open the CMD as administrator.

Comment: I think my problem lies with the FABRIC_CFG_PATH environment variable. Can u explain in which directory or how I should use this export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/configtx/configtx.yaml. what I did is setting a new variable FABRIC_CFG_PATH in the User Variable section

Answer (score 0):

Use `FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/` with your $PWD set to `~/fabric-samples/fabcar`

Also check that configtx.yaml exists in `~/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx`

Comment: First I went back to config folder under fabric-samples and run this-    
    export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
then I went to fabcar folder and run 
    echo $FABRIC_CFG_PATH and it was showing the perfect path. Then I ran startFabric.sh but still showing the error

Comment: Check my updated answer. Confirm you have the most recent fabric-samples.